# Not able to check a button is disabled or not in protractor

Tags: protractor

When i try to check a button is disabled or not, it gives an error

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to be true
```

I am using protractor-cucumber with protractor version 5.2.2,cucumber version 3.2.0 and chai library.

my code is

```
expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login')).getAttribute('disabled')).to.be.true;
```

when i am try to get a string value using getText() method, it also gives this type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
return expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login')).getAttribute('disabled')).to.eventually.equals('true');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use assertion in correct way like below.

```
expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBe('true')
```

Also to check if something is enabled or disabled, You should use isEnabled().

like this - `expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login').isEnabled()).toBe([true|false]);`

Or if you are using PageObject then work like below:

//Page class

```
this.yourElement = element(by.css('.frx-btn-login');

this.checkElement = function () {

    return this.yourElement.isEnabled();
}
};
```

//Spec class:

```
  page.checkElement().then(function (val) {
      expect(val).toBe([true|false]);
    });
```

Comment: i tried with
    expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login')).getAttribute('disabled')).to.be.true;
and
    expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login')).isEnabled()).to.be.true;
but it gives same error.when i console it,returns the object not the value.

Comment: @Rose Please check carefully you are making same mistake again. you should not use .to.be.true rather, expect(element(by.css('.frx-btn-login').isEnabled()).toBe([true|false]); Read my answer carefully. It will help